# float:right works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: css

- [Chrome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6nNn.png)
- [Firefox output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/639OS.png)

```css
.continue-btn {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 55px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 6% 0%;
}
.heading-one {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: Nexabold;
}
```

```html
<div class="" id="continue-page2" >
 <a class="btn continue-btn heading-two" href="#"> CONTINUE   <span class="fa fa-arrow-right "></span></a>
</div>
```

In Firefox, the span is displayed in next line in the button. If I make a change in CSS its affected in Chrome.

Comment: Probably you have box sizing or something where you need to add prefix for mozila

Answer (score -1):

In Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit)
Following code works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
 .continue-btn {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 55px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 6% 0%;
}
.heading-two {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: Nexabold;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="" id="continue-page2" >
    <a class="btn continue-btn heading-two" href="#"> CONTINUE   
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the images

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: In Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit) Following code works fine. Which version of Mozilla you are using?

Answer (score -1):

See the code below. Hope this will work for you.

```css
#continue-page2 {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#continue-page2 .btn {
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

#continue-page2 span {
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  float: right;
  background-color: #831A24;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="continue-page2" >
   <a class="btn continue-btn heading-two" href="#">CONTINUE
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?